# Can I treat latitude/longitude as (x,y) coordinates to find closest point?

Tags: coordinate-systems

I have a list of coordinates L(lat, lon) and a specific position X.
I am interested in finding the nearest location from the list L to the position X.
Can I treat the lat, lon as x, y and implement [the planar case approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem)?

Comment: Only _very_ locally. It is easy to see for example that close to the poles things get strange. Stand one foot from the pole and you have 180 degrees difference to the point opposite (but only two feet in practice), which would be as large if you treated it as x coordinate as opposite side the world if you were anywhere along the equator!

Comment: @mathreadler:Is there a way I can do better than the brute force? I was hoping that somehow I could apply the planar case

Comment: Technically, [you cannot do it locally either](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorema_Egregium). There exists no distance-preserving diffeomorphism from an open set of $S^2$ to an open set of $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: I added a small expansion how to get a better approximation than just guessing x and y equal to angles. If the range of angles is small enough it should work reasonably, but it only gives you better input coordinates to feed whatever algorithm you want to find closest point with.

Answer (score 1):

No, consider these two pairs of points in (lat, long):

- $(0^\circ,0^\circ)$ and $(89.9^\circ,0^\circ)$
- $(89.9^\circ, 0^\circ)$ and $(89.9^\circ, 180^\circ)$

The first pair is $89.9^\circ$ apart, and the second pair is $0.2^\circ$ apart, but the first pair in your $(x,y)$ coordinates is closer.

Comment: Is there a way I can do better than the brute force? I was hoping that somehow I could apply the planar case

Answer (score 0):

**Just a hint**

A better way would be to switch to cartesian coordinates in ${\mathbb R}^3$ and then approximate distance as length of difference between these cartesian vectors. But it would require many calculations of sin and cos functions to do so. Here is a more computationally saving approach.

If you allow yourself to do a local transformation, you can do rectangular transforms like those you see on globes. For example at the wikipedia page for [Mercator Projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection), consider the passage on **small element geometry**, where you can calculate x and y of corner points of a local patch, calculate linear scale factors to transfer $\phi,\theta$ to $x,y$ this in some sense compensates for the "stretch" that the cylindrical transform has done. The relative scale factor will be $\cos(\phi)$ which will only become catastrophic (go to $0 / \infty$) around the poles at $\phi=\pm90^\circ$. So you will need to switch coordinates, but given that the range of angles are rather small, you should be able to get a good approximation.